# Não consigo usar o LoginButton do Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk

Toda vez tento inserir ele a aplicação compila mas não executa, fecha automaticamente com a seguinte exceção`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.speedle.android/com.bryderi.speedle.android.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
>           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
>           at com.bryderi.speedle.android.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/se.speedle.android-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.speedle.android-1, /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
>               at com.bryderi.speedle.android.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

Já busquei no Stack gringo e alguns dizem pra chamar o método SdkInitialize, só que esse método atualmente é obsoleto e o Sdk já inicializa sozinho. Mesmo chamando não funciona. Alguém tem uma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Já existem várias [perguntas com resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5Dlogin+do+Facebook) sobre o assunto, verifique se alguma lhe atende.

Comment: Tente editar sua pergunta e inserir o código que você acha relevante nela. Por exemplo o XML.

Comment: As respostas abaixo te atente ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!

Comment: Não. Acabei fazendo de outro jeito, conforme a documentação do Facebook. Eliminei os erros, compila, executa mas ainda não está sendo possível fazer o login se puder derem uma olhada no GitHub...
https://github.com/DouglasDRF/Approach/issues

Answer (score 0):

O erro que está dando na sua aplicação é exatamente ao inflar o `LoginButton`:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error
>   inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton at

Se estiver usando Facebook SDK 4+ você precisa alterar a *tag* do seu botão para `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` no seu XML. Veja:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLoginFabook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Login com Fabook" />
```

Caso contrário deve permanecer `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`.